# Как настроить в wordpress переадресацию с домена на подраздел сайта в зависимости от местоположения пользователя?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, домен, поддомены

Т.е. надо чтобы с сайта site.ru для русскоязычных переадресовывалось на site.ru/ru, а для других на site.ru/en (настроил эти подразделы через функцию мультисайтов на wordpress)

Comment: В вопросе огромное противоречие: местоположение и язык - кардинально разные вещи. В своем ответе я предположил, что нужно определять язык, чтобы показывать раздел на нужном языке.

Answer (score 2):

Добавьте в functions.php

```
function switch_language() {
    $avail_langs = array("en", "ru");
    $lang = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);
    if (in_array($lang, $avail_langs)) {
        if( is_home() ){
            $url = get_home_url() . "/" . $lang . "/";
            wp_redirect( $url );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'switch_language' );
```